# How to jump to the first error when using ALE?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-ale

I've installed dense-analysis/ale from this repo: https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale

I'm trying to use it to detect errors automatically in my Elm projects.

Errors are detected since they are highlighted with a ">>" in red.
However, since my source file is pretty long, it's impossible for me to know immediately whether there's an error or not.

A solution should be to type `:cn` to jump to the next error. But then I just get the reply "E42: No Error". And it doesn't jump to the error, even when there's an error in the file.

I'd like to be notified immediately when there's an error, or, alternatively, be able to check with a simple command like `:cn`.

How to achieve that?

My setup:

- vim version 8.2
- elm version 0.19.1
- elm-language-server version 2.4.1
- elm-format 0.8.5
- ALE v3.2.0 (I actually just cloned the project into my .vim/bundle  directory)

Comment: Yes! `ALENext` is working, thank you!

Comment: I you want to rewrite this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: **If** you want to rewrite this. That was a typo.

Comment: Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:ALENext` command to jump to the next error found by ALE.

See [`:help ale-navigation-commands`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/doc/ale.txt#L3565) for the list of navigation commands provided by ALE itself.

If you'd like to create mappings for quicker navigation, ALE also exposes some `<Plug>` mappings that you can map to key combinations that suit you.

[This entry](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#5xi-how-can-i-navigate-between-errors-quickly) in ALE's README.md suggests a setup using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to jump to the previous/next error, respectively:

```
nmap <silent> <C-k> <Plug>(ale_previous_wrap)
nmap <silent> <C-j> <Plug>(ale_next_wrap)
```